# Android: how to check in BroadCast Receiver that activity has been completed once

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have 3 activities which a BroadCast Receiver start. I want to check in BroadCast Receiver the 3 activities that which one was the last one finished and the second finished and then run the third activity. And do check all the time before starting an activity. Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `SharedPreferences`. When an activity is about to finish, write this event in the `SharedPreferences`. In the `BroadcastReceiver`, check this event.

PS: Let me know if you need more details on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Make one satic counter for increment
```

> Static int counter_Activity=0;

```
Do for all Three Activity

counter_Activity++;
finish();
pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString(counter_Activity,Activity_name);
editor.commit();


For Checking in Brodcast Class.

pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
pref.getInt(1,Activity_name-1); 
pref.getInt(2,Activity_name-2); 
pref.getInt(3,Activity_name-3);
```

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by `Activity_name` and `Activity_name-1` and you are putting String in pref and getting int?